# Msg 9002 The transaction log for database 'myDataBase' is full due to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть база данных myDataBase в ней есть таблица myTable в таблице около двух миллионов записей. При попытке добавить столбец к этой таблице

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.myTable ADD myTable_id int identity(1,1) not null primary key
```

получаю ошибку:

> Msg 9002 The transaction log for database 'myDataBase' is full due to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION'.**

Из сообщения понятно что переполнен журнал transaction log

После этого увеличил размер log файла:

```
ALTER DATABASE myDataBase
MODIFY FILE
    (NAME = myDataBase_log ,
     MAXSIZE = 170MB)
GO
```

и применил команду:

```
CHECKPOINT
    DBCC SHRINKFILE ('myDataBase_log')
```

До выполнения команды: 
`ALTER TABLE dbo.myTable ADD myTable_id int identity(1,1) not null primary key` 
размер log файла 27MB после 150MB и всё равно ошибка Msg 9002. Подскажите как в данной ситуации поступить:

- Увеличивать размер log файла? если увеличивать то на сколько?
- Нормальное ли это поведение log файла?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, это нормальное поведение.

SQL Server немедленно пишет все вносимые вами изменения в transaction log.

Ваш ALTER требует полного пересоздания таблицы - т.к. вы добавляете кластерный индекс. Соответственно, в лог будут записано удаление старых данных + вставка их заново, с попутным пересозданием всех индексов. Так что объем лог-файла стоит увеличить минимум до 2x размера таблицы (лучше 4x).

Я бы на вашем месте выставил размер лога не исходя из размера базы, а исходя из доступного места на диске (т.е. все свободное место минус минимальный запас). или вообще снял ограничение.

Размер таблицы + размер индексов можно посмотреть в View / Object Explorer Details в Management Studio.

Comment: т.е если размер таблицы ~300MB то объём лога увеличивать до 600MB...

Comment: @VladimirTsybin да. а лучше больше 1000.